# AWS charges for spark read from S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How does AWS charges for reading data from S3 via spark.
Is it comes under GET request  or data retrieval ?

Can someone please explain with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is documented in [S3 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)'s:

**Data Retrieval:**

`Amazon S3 data retrieval pricing applies for the S3 Standard-Infrequent Access (S3 Standard-IA) and S3 One Zone-IA storage classes and is summarized on the Amazon S3 Pricing page.`

Hence for standard data objects, reading data from S3 via Spark falls under the category of GET requests.

[S3 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) reference.

Comment: note also that it's usually >1 GET per file read for anything doing random seek/read IO, e.g. parquet or ORC reads.